# Search type in Catalog don't search by Product's Name

Tags: magento-1, catalogsearch, search-criteria, search-terms

I'm changed catalog search configuration to :

System > Configuration > Catalog

- Search Type => Combine (Like and Fulltext)
- Product Listing Sort by  => Name

[image]

[image]

But when I search by name, the product not showing in the top page. His appear in the middle of the page

Think that I forget the some configuration

Can help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System > Configuration > Catalog

settings are not enough to sort the catalog search results. You need to add this in your theme layout override xml file (probably local.xml)

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="search_result_list">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><param>asc</param></action>
        <action method="setSortBy"><param>name</param></action>
    </reference>
  </catalogsearch_result_index>
```

For further information you can check these answers

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/44633/695

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293342/777103